# Cassandra Titan create own DB

Tags: cassandra, titan, database, nosql

I am starting with titan and i am really loosing in it. I created my own graph databse model with tables(Vertices) and relations(Edge). Well, now I want to create my DB, but I cannot find any good tutorial. How to build scripts? Do you have same example how to create own verticles and edges? 
Thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are new to graphs and new to Titan, start here:

http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/0.5.4/getting-started.html

If you don't follow that then recognize that Titan implements the [Blueprints](http://blueprints.tinkerpop.com) interfaces (i.e. [TinkerPop](http://tinkerpop.com)) and thus is accessible via the Gremlin graph traversal language:

https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/wiki/Getting-Started

There are plenty of resources available that explain how these things work.  Consider looking at [GremlinDocs](http://gremlindocs.com/) as well as [Sql2Gremlin](http://sql2gremlin.com/) as well.